# Why is my Libgdx ScrollPane not scrolling horizontally?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi I am trying to build a horizontal scrolling screen in my libgdx game but can only get it to scroll vertically rather than horizontally for some reason.  Although the `ScrollPane` sounds simple I don't fully understand it for some reason but a scrolling credits example on here helped me a little.

I have a table and have added rows of text to it. The table matches the size of the screen and it also contains a `ScrollPane` called `scroller` which fills the size of the table. I am guessing since the rows of text don't fit on the screen and therefore the `scroller`, the `scroller` automatically allows vertically scrolling in the credits example?  However when I change the text to one long line of text rather than new lines the `scroller` doesn't allow me to scroll horizontally to view all the text why is that?  Surely the text is going outside the `scroller` width?

```
scrollTable = new Table();    //create table
scrollTable.add(text);    //add a long line of text bigger than screen
scrollTable.row();
scrollTable.add(text2);
scrollTable.row();
scrollTable.add(text3);
scroller = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);  //create the ScrollPane

Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
table.add(scroller).fill().expand();
//scroller.setWidth(500);
//scroller.setScrollingDisabled(false, true);
stage.addActor(table);

private static final String reallyLongString = 
"This is a really long string that has lots of lines and repeats itself over and over again This is a really long string that has" +
" lots of lines and repeats itself over and over again This is a really long string that has lots of lines and repeats itself over and over"+
" again This is a really long string that has lots of lines and repeats itself over and over again"+
" This is a really long string that has lots of lines and repeats itself over and over again This is a really long string that has lots"+
" of lines and repeats itself over and over again";
//This is my long string of text.
```

Comment: I believe `ScrollPane` only works horizontally...

Comment: How do I get it to work horizontally.  It works either vertically or horizontally and should automatically do either when the item/object goes outside its container bounds I believe.

Comment: I think it only does one... Try using two?

Comment: No says here should automatically adjust when the actor is bigger than the ScrollPane. http://libgdx-users.googlecode.com/git-history/98938776a3c246953b8719afbcb9bc3b5ac15665/gdx-shared-libs/libs/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html

Comment: Do you have an inner container and an outer container?

Comment: Think so.  I have the two tables above in the code thats everything I have to do with the ScrollPane

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Table table = new Table();
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(table);
```

Comment: You should explain your answer in more detail. What does it do and why does it work?

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html